# Animated TextInput dismisses the keyboard after each character

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I'm animating the `TextInput` to move with `translateY`, but when I apply the React Native `animated`, `TextInput` responds to typing only one character at a time. What I mean is, once a character has been input, the keyboard is dismissed.

I have three animations happening and others are working fine:

```js
    const [textInputAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(animation, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 800,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            }),
            Animated.timing(textInputAnimation, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 400,
                delay: 700,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            }),
            Animated.timing(logoAnimation, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 400,
                delay: 900,
                useNativeDriver: true,
            })
        ]).start()
    }, [])
    const translateYInterpolate = textInputAnimation.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [-50, 0]
    })

    const animatedOpacity = textInputAnimation.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1]
    })

    const animatedTranslateStyle = {
        transform: [
            {
                translateY: translateYInterpolate
            }
        ],
        opacity: animatedOpacity,
    }

    const AnimatedTextInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput);
```

The animated `TextInput`:

```js
<AnimatedTextInput
    style={[styles.textInput, animatedTranslateStyle]}
    onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
    value={value}
    placeholder="Search for an item"
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
    clearButtonMode={'always'}
    returnKeyType="search"
    selectionColor="red"
/>
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: but ```Animated.View``` is already a animated library component?